# Modelling a linear minimization program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, alternative-proof, operations-research

[image]

Attempt:

Let

$x_l=$ number of barrel of light crude oil.

$x_h=$ number of barrel of heavy crude oil.

Then we should have as objective function

$z=20x_l+15x_h$

And as conditions

s.t. $.4x_l+.32x_h\ge1000000000\\ .2x_l+.4x_h\ge500000\\ .35x_l+.2x_h\ge300,000\\ x_l,x_h\ge0$

Now I am not sure how to add the condition $5\%$  and $8\%$ lost during the refining process.

I though in substracting each of them in each inequality.

Would that be correct?

Someone please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I am not sure how to add the condition $5\%$  and $8\%$ lost during the refining process.

prubin has already provided a nice answer, but it seems that you don't get what he says.

See the table.

For light crude oil, add the numbers and you'll get $0.4+0.2+0.35=0.95$ which equals $1-0.05$.

For heavy crude oil, the sum of the numbers is $0.32+0.4+0.2=0.92$ which equals $1-0.08$.

These mean that the loss has already been taken into account.

Hence, we want to minimize $20x_l+15x_h$ under the following conditions :

$$\begin{cases}0.4x_l+0.32x_h\ge 10^6
\\\\ 0.2x_l+0.4x_h\ge 500000
\\\\ 0.35x_l+0.2x_h\ge300000
\\\\ x_l,x_h\ge0\end{cases}$$

Note that you have a typo in the RHS of the first inequality.

---

Letting $x_l=x,x_h=y$ and considering the graphs, we see that $20x+15y$ is minimized at which the lines $x=0$ and $0.4x+0.32y=10^6$ intersect. (Note that the slope of the line $20x+15y=k$ is $-1.\dot 3$ and that the slope of the line $0.4x+0.32y=10^6$ is $-1.25$.)

$\qquad\qquad $[image]

Therefore, the answer is
$$20\times 0+15\times\frac{10^6}{0.32}=\color{red}{46875000}$$

---

**Added** :

Let $k=20x+15y$ which can be written as $y=-\frac 43x+\frac{k}{15}$. We want to minimize $k$, so that means that we want to minimize the $y$-intercept of the line $y=-\frac 43x+\frac{k}{15}$. Considering the region that the inequalities satisfy, the $y$-intercept is minimized at the red point where the lines $x=0$ and $0.4x+0.32y=10^6$ intersect.

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I got it. I have a question, How did you notice in the graph that $20x+15y$ is minimized at which lines  $0.4x+0.32y=10^6$ and $y=0$ interesect?

Comment: @Alt.: Let $k=20x+15y$ which can be written as $y=-\frac 43x+\frac{k}{15}$. Then, the $y$-intercept of this line $y=-\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{k}{15}$ is $\frac{k}{15}$. Since we want to miniimze $k$, that means that we want to minimize the $y$-intercept. So, we need to consider a line with slope $-\frac 34$ and the smallest $y$-intercept. Now, considering the region that the inequalities satisfy in my answer, you'll see that the $y$-intercept is minimized at which the two lines intersect (note that $x=0$, not $y=0$). If you still have something unclear, let me know. I'll explain more.

Comment: @Alt.: I've added some explanations in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @mathlove

Comment: How did you make the second plot? What software did you use? .I have a new l.p. question and I need to plot the region. I usually use mathematica though my plots look ugly..

Comment: @Alt. : The second one is by [Illustrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator), not by a mathematical tool. In other words, I just drew the second one by myself.

Comment: ah, Illustrator.. it looks really nice. And the first one?

Comment: @Alt. : The first one is by [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the coefficients in each row of the output table. You'll see that the loss has already been taken into account.

Comment: Which coefficients are you refering to?

Comment: The 2x3 table in the scanned problem statement. Sum each row of the table.